# display data into textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how to display result from data base into textbox and if the result exceed 1 key up and down to preview

```
 con = New SqlConnection(cs)
con.Open()
Dim sql As String = " Select RTRIM(visit.regdate),RTRIM(Patientno) from visit where visit.accno =@d6 "
cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d6", accno.Text)
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While (rdr.Read() = True)

    regdate.Value = rdr.GetValue(0)
    patientno.Text = rdr.GetValue(1)

End While
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What results do you want, or what problem do you have? What have you tried?

Comment: when user enter visit no into textbox the system retrieve  the last record only , the problem is that i want to change between records

Comment: You should Edit your question and add requested details to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You must use listbox instead textbox to put your data, here is an example:

```
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3 
ListBox1.Columnwidths = "100,100,100" 
ListBox1.AddListItem("row1 col1", 1,1) 
ListBox1.AddListItem("row1 col2", 1,2)
ListBox1.AddListItem("row2 col2", 2,2)
```